Gnuplot declares non-grid data
I am using gnuplot patch level 6.0.1. suddenly it declares a gridded data as non-grid data for contour plot. kindly advise what to do? I have shared an image of part of the data-file the grid-data file for reference.
A solution to treat this file as grid-data

I checked again. Somehow VI editor declares [noeol][dos] for the data file which is in .txt format
